# Is it possible to disable the message authentication check in AES/CCM on Android?

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I am working on some code that receives AES/CCM encrypted packets but without the MAC appended. This causes me a problem in Java as the library expects the MAC to be there. Here is the snippet of code that performs the decryption:

```
javax.crypto.Cipher out = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CCM/NoPadding", "BC");
out.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec.IvParameterSpec(nonce));
byte[] decrypted = out.doFinal(encrypted);
```

When executed this fails on my input because the 8 bytes of MAC is not appended to the end of the `encrypted` array. The error message is: `Encryption failed : MAC check in CCM failed`. Is there a way to set up the decryption using the Java libraries such that the MAC is not expected? Unfortunately I have no control over the format of the data sent to me by the remote device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCM is CBC with MAC. If you do not want to use authentication field, just use AES/CBC.

Comment: This is something I had already tried, but AES/CBC insists on a fixed IV size, AES/CCM does not. I need to spend the time reading up on how the different encryption standards work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Bouncy Castle, by setting `macSize` to 0 in `AEADParameterSpec`. The example below assumes that `ciphertext` has the MAC appended. In your case, adjust for the fact that it missing by calling `cipher.doFinal(ciphertext)` instead of `cipher.doFinal(ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.length - LENGTH_MAC_TAG)`.

```
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] key,
                             byte[] nonce,
                             byte[] additional,  // null to disable MAC check
                             byte[] ciphertext) {
        
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CCM/NoPadding", "BC");
        
    AlgorithmParameterSpec parameterSpec;
    if (additional == null) {
        parameterSpec = new AEADParameterSpec(nonce, 0);
    } else {
        parameterSpec = new AEADParameterSpec(nonce, LENGTH_MAC_TAG * 8);
    }
    
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), parameterSpec);
    
    byte[] plaintext;
    
    if (additional == null) {
        plaintext = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.length - LENGTH_MAC_TAG);
    } else {
        cipher.updateAAD(additional);
        plaintext = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
    }
    
    return plaintext;
}
```